# Filter by group max combination of values in a given order

Tags: r

I would like to filter by groups, the maximal combination of values based on a given order of columns.

A vector of column should specify the order of columns in which looking at maximal values.

For example :

```
x <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), 
                x = c(1, 1, 1, 2), 
                y = c(1, 2, 2, 1), 
                z = c(1, 1, 2, 1))

> x
  id x y z
1  a 1 1 1
2  a 1 2 1
3  b 1 2 2
4  b 2 1 1
```

In this example I would like to group by `id` and set the 'priority' to `x, y, z` which means that I want to look the maximal `x` value, then it's associated maximal `y` value and then the maximal `z` value for the maximal `x, y` couple.

I'm not aware of such a vectorized function so I reccursively group to find the maximum following column maximal value :

```
> x
  id x y z
1  a 1 2 1
2  b 2 1 1
```

I can do it with base R, with a loop :

```
group <- "id"
cols <- c("x", "y", "z")

for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
  tmp <- aggregate(setNames(list(x[[cols[i]]]), cols[i]), by = as.list(x[group]), FUN = max)
  x <- merge(x, tmp, by = c(group, cols[i]))
  group <- c(group, cols[i])
}

x <- x[!duplicated(x), ]

> x
  id x y z
1  a 1 2 1
2  b 2 1 1
```

I would like to apply this to larger amount of data, so this code will struggle at some point. Do you have any ideas to improve this ?

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 3):

We can try with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   arrange(desc(y),desc(z)) %>% 
   slice(which.max(x))
#     id     x     y     z  
#   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1      a     1     2     1
#2      b     2     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution using the split-apply-combine methodology.

```
dfNew <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, x$id),
                               function(x) x[with(x, order(x, y, z, decreasing=TRUE))[1],]))
```

which returns

```
dfNew    
  id x y z
a  a 1 2 1
b  b 2 1 1
```

`split` splits the dataframe by id and returns a list, This list is fed to `lapply` which then applies an anonymous function that returns the row with the maximum values according to `order`. Finally, the list of single row data.frames are appended with `rbind` and `do.call`.